# how to improve performance of android multiple screens app

Tags: java, android, xml, performance

how to improve performance of android multiple screens app.Do I use activities for controllers and fragments for views likewise or is there any other structure i could use. I learned that nested layouts could slow down your app and not closing Handlers also leaks memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your requirement and according to that you should use component as well as layouts for application.

**Let's see some possible ways for improve performance:**

- When you are working with images, try to release all views when not
  in use.
- If your screens are dependent then try to work with drawer and
  fragments to load quickly.
- When ever you are working with database or network, never run such
  task on main thread use async task for same to improve performance.
- When you are using list or recycle view for list data, never directly load images inside, use lazy loading to improve performance.

  - Use local cache to store temporary data to improve performance.

Comment: thanks @Vikash. Is there any reference materials that will elaborate more widely with examples.

Comment: you can go through https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/index.html

it will help you for understanding better performance task